# How to resolve Koala2 package dependency issue?

Tags: python

I have some code that I wrote that relies on the Koala2 package. The code was running a few weeks ago but has since stopped working. The following code throws an error

```
!pip install koala2
from koala.ExcelCompiler import ExcelCompiler


ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-715ed1f6c9fe> in <module>()
----> 1 from koala.ExcelCompiler import ExcelCompiler
  2 from koala.Spreadsheet import Spreadsheet
  3 import pandas as pd
  4 import numpy as np
  5 import string

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/koala/__init__.py in <module>()
    2 
      3 from openpyxl import *
----> 4 from .ast import *
  5 from .Cell import *
  6 from .ExcelCompiler import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/koala/ast/__init__.py in <module>()
  7 import networkx
  8 from networkx.classes.digraph import DiGraph
----> 9 from openpyxl.compat import unicode
 10 
 11 from koala.utils import uniqueify, flatten, max_dimension, col2num,                resolve_range

ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode' from 'openpyxl.compat'
(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/compat/__init__.py)
```

This code is taken directly from the very first example that they have on [PYPI](https://pypi.org/project/koala2/)

I can get around this by:

```
!pip install openpyxl==2.5.14
```

But then I am no longer able to use Pandas read_excel() because it requires openpyxl >= 3.0.0

This is strange to me because as I mentioned earlier, everything was running ok a few weeks ago and I don't think there are new versions of koala or openpyxl. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Also it looks like Koalas has been abandoned by its creators. My goal was to read in an excel file, record where the formulas are and be able to apply these formulas to a new excel file or data frame with the same layout and dimensions (# or rows and columns) as the original excel. If there is a better way to do this without koalas any insight would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: try to use older version of pandas to satisfy requirements. PS `from openpyxl.compat import unicode` works at least with `openpyxl==2.6.2` (maybe newer versions also will be work)

Comment: Yeah I tried 1.3.5. I'll go further back and continue to try older versions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like that is [known problem](https://github.com/vallettea/koala/issues/241) from 2019.
2. Koala code [don't updated](https://github.com/vallettea/koala) more than 2 years (maybe you should search newer alternative?).

Here is two possible solutions:

1. Use older versions of all other libraries in your code to keep dependencies
2. Patch Koala library manually everytime when you install it:

> Until the bugfix is put into the repository, the fix I made locally is: replace the "from openpyxl.compat import unicode" line with "unicode = str" in all the koala files that have it.